# Read an xml into List of class

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class:

```
public class AcceptedCardTypes
{ 
    private string _cardType = string.Empty;
    private string _cardName = string.Empty;

    public string CardType
    {
        get { return _cardType; }
        set { _cardType = value; }
    }

    public string CardName
    {
        get { return _cardName; }
        set { _cardName = value; }
    } 
}
```

I have one object of this class:

```
public List<AcceptedCardTypes> _acceptedCardTypes = new List<AcceptedCardTypes>();
```

I have an xml:

```
<Purchase purchaseToken="O3320604812" timeToExpiration="1798218">
    <ServiceList>
        <AcceptedCardTypes>
            <Card type="AE">American Express</Card> 
            <Card type="MC">MasterCard</Card> 
            <Card type="VI">Visa</Card> 
        </AcceptedCardTypes>
    </ServiceList>
</Purchase>
```

I want to read the aforementioned xml in

```
_acceptedCardTypes object using LINQ.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784328/linq-reading-xml-to-object-list?rq=1

Comment: @palak what have you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After loading the xml into an `XElement` object you can try this:

```
_acceptedCardTypes =
    xml
        .Descendants("Card")
        .Select(x => new AcceptedCardTypes()
        {
            CardName = x.Value,
            CardType = x.Attribute("type").Value,
        })
        .ToList();
```

Or to add to the existing list do this:

```
_acceptedCardTypes
    .AddRange(
        xml
            .Descendants("Card")
            .Select(x => new AcceptedCardTypes()
            {
                CardName = x.Value,
                CardType = x.Attribute("type").Value,
            }));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the XmlSerializer or the DataContractSerializer for  Serialization/Deserialization of your List, you not have to parse
it manually with Linq

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have this XMl in a file `C:\test\data.txt`, this this code will read the values and map them into your `AcceptedCardTypes` class as an `IEnumerable<AcceptedCardType>`:

```
void Main()
{
    var xd = XDocument.Load(@"C:\test\data.txt");
    var cardTypes = xd.Element("Purchase")
                       .Element("ServiceList")
                       .Element("AcceptedCardTypes")
                       .Elements("Card")
                        .Select(e=>new AcceptedCardTypes{
                            CardType=e.Attribute("type").Value,CardName=e.Value});
}
```

Note: You *can* do it by just selecting all "Card" descendants as in

```
 xd.Descendants("Card")
       .Select(e=>new AcceptedCardTypes{
          CardType=e.Attribute("type").Value,CardName=e.Value
        });
```

But that assumes you won't have "Card" elements somewhere else in your XML that you don't want to read, i.e the first version is more explicit about the location the "Card" elements are being read from.